# R - Performance between subset and creating DF from vectors

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if there is a huge performance difference/impact for large datasets when you try to subset the data.

In my scenario, I have a dataframe with just under 29,000 records/data.

When I had to subset the data, I thought of 2 ways to do this.

The data is read from a csv file using reactive.

option 1

```
long_lat_df <- reactive({
  long_lat <- subset(readFile(), select=c(Latitude..deg.,Longitude..deg.))
  return(long_lat)
})
```

option 2
what I had in mind was to extract the 2 columns and assign the 2 columns to its own variable long and lat. From there I can combine the 2 columns to form a new data frame where I can use it to work with spatial analysis.

Would there be a potential performance impact between the 2 options?

Comment: The way to find out is to try it.  You can easily measure the performance on your specific data and machine.

Comment: The overhead from subsetting is tiny and will not be your bottleneck. (Evaluating expressions to use to subset may be another matter.) It's a good idea to keep your data in a consistent meaningful structure, though; subsetting out vectors and then reassembling a data.frame offers potential for data to become misaligned. Also, `?subset` warns against programmatic use; it's safer to just use `[`/`[[`.

Comment: Another option: use `data.table::fread()` to load your data instead of `readFile`. Then you can use the `select` argument to provide a vector of column names or numbers to keep.  My guess this is much faster than the other options you suggest.  Try them all and see.